# Does $unionWith run parallel query on independent collections?

Tags: mongodb

Think that I have 3 collections. I want to run $unionWith to fetch data from those three collections.

```
        db.getCollection('BlogPostLikers').aggregate([
            {$match:{likerId:ObjectId('5eb17cf53f0000020ac10c75')}},
            {$unionWith: { coll: "PostOrBlogs", pipeline: [{ $match: { postType: 'T' } }] }} ,
            {$unionWith: { coll: "PaySlip", pipeline: [{ $match: { employeeId: ObjectId('5eb17cf53f0000020ac10c75') } }] }} ,

    ])
```

Will this be parallel or sequential ?

Comment: Is it important to know if two collections return just one document?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit No, it will return 3 collections related separate documents in a single list. Here no stages are related to each other.

Comment: Unless you can find something in the manual that states that stages can be executed concurrently, I would assume that each stage is executed after the previous one.

Comment: @D.SM yes, your are right. I asked this question to the mongodb forum : https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/does-unionwith-run-parallel-query-on-independent-collections/13738

Comment: There's a MongoDB Jira ticket to track this: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-48118